# How to compare pointer to string without strcmp?

Tags: c, string, command-line, compare

One input taken from command line and the other from the function?

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    search(argv[1]);
}

int search(char *pointer)
{
    char *s1 = "hello";
    int t;
    t = 0;

    if (pointer == s1)
        { t = 1; }
    else
        { t = 0; }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the source code for strcmp. [Apple](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-262/ppc/gen/strcmp.c) and [Android](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/ics-mr0/libc/string/strcmp.c) and [GNU](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/string/strcmp.c.html). Learn from these how to implement one.

Comment: Why without strcmp?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just compare strings like pointer == s1 in c.
You need to compare all characters in string. That's why you need a loop

```
int search(char *pointer)
{
   char *s1 = "hello";

   int t=1 ;
   int i=0;

      while(s1[i]!='\0' && pointer[i] !='\0'){
         if(s1[i] != pointer[i]){
            t = 0;
            break;
         }
          i++;
         if(t==0)
            return 0;
         else
            return 1;

      }       
}
```

You can call from main like this:

```
int main (int argc,char *argv[])
{
   if(search(argv[1]) == 1){
      printf("Equal");
   }
   else{
      printf("Not equal");
   }
}
```